# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de la celda seleccionada DataGridView C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tengo un datagridview y lo que quiero es que al dar dobleclick este me muestre la información en un textbox, pero al querer hacer la selección me toma la fila de arriba.

¿Cómo selecciono la fila? es con este código, que lo tengo en una clase:

```
public void SeleccionarDatosGrid(DataGridView dataGridView1, TextBox textBox1, TextBox textBox2)
        {
            int FilaActual = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string query = "SELECT Id,PersonalEnsamble,Descripcion FROM OrdenesDeTrabajo WHERE Id=@Id";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FilaActual;
                    try
                    {
                        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        if (rd.Read())
                        {
                            textBox1.Text = rd["Descripcion"].ToString();
                            textBox2.Text = rd["PersonalEnsamble"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(SqlException ex)
                    {
                        string mensaje = ex.Message;
                        MessageBox.Show(mensaje, "Excepcion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Luego al evento lo mando llamar

```
private void GrindOrdenes_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    OrdenesDeTrabajo OT = new OrdenesDeTrabajo();
    OT.SeleccionarDatosGrid(GrindOrdenes, txtArticulo, txtPersonal);
}
```

Tengo entendido que debería tomar la fila actual, pero no es así

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es agregar esa línea de código en el evento: DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick

Comment: @hdmq asi lo hice, lo que tengo es una clase con esta funcion, luego la mando llamar, anexo el codigo en la publicacion

Answer (score 0):

Quite la clase y lo hice directo en el form de esta manera y me funciono

```
private void GrindOrdenes_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int FilaActual = Convert.ToInt32(GrindOrdenes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);

            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string query = "SELECT Id,PersonalEnsamble,Descripcion FROM OrdenesDeTrabajo WHERE Id=@Id";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FilaActual;
                    try
                    {
                        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        if (rd.Read())
                        {
                            txtArticulo.Text = rd["Descripcion"].ToString();
                            txtPersonal.Text = rd["PersonalEnsamble"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        string mensaje = ex.Message;
                        MessageBox.Show(mensaje, "Excepcion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```